# Include JNI header on Android Lib with Bazel

Tags: android, java-native-interface, bazel

I'm trying to use JNI with Bazel (0.12.0):

WORKSPACE file:

```
android_ndk_repository(
    name = "androidndk",
)
```

libs/hello_lib_c/BUILD:

```
cc_library(
    name = "hello_lib_c",
    srcs = ["src/hello.c"],
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
)
```

libs/hello_lib_c/src/hello.c:

```
#include <jni.h>

JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL
Java_eu_tamere_bazel_HelloJNI_hello(JNIEnv *env, jclass clazz) {
  return (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, "Hello from JNI ");
}
```

libs/hello_lib_java/BUILD:

```
android_library(
    name = "hello_lib_java",
    srcs = glob(["src/eu/tamere/bazel/**"]),
    deps = ["//libs/hello_lib_c"],
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
)
```

When building the Java lib, the `jni.h` header file is not found. Any idea on how to declare the dependency?

```
$ bazel build //libs/hello_lib_java
INFO: Analysed target //libs/hello_lib_java:hello_lib_java (22 packages loaded).
INFO: Found 1 target...
ERROR: /path/to/project/libs/hello_lib_c/BUILD:1:1: C++ compilation of rule '//libs/hello_lib_c:hello_lib_c' failed (Exit 1)
libs/hello_lib_c/src/hello.c:1:10: fatal error: jni.h: No such file or directory
 #include <jni.h>
          ^~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
Target //libs/hello_lib_java:hello_lib_java failed to build
Use --verbose_failures to see the command lines of failed build steps.
```

I've tried  to add `hdrs = ["@androidndk//:jni_header"],` to the `cc_library` definition but it does now work either. I've also tried to explicitly set the `path` for the Android NDK in the `WORKSPACE`but it does not change.

The [android example on the official repo](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/tree/master/examples/android/java/bazel) does not specify where to find the jni lib.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that using JNI inside an `android_library` (i.e., `.aar`) is not possible at the moment without some tricks. Only `android_binary` (i.e., `.apk`) will link the jni lib.

From https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/348 :

> android_library .aar output does not currently support bundling native libraries. This is a known deficiency that I believe @dkelmer has plans to work on.

aj-michael has a repo with a workaround:

https://github.com/aj-michael/aar_with_jni